# Not a number in PHP, getting an error message

Tags: php, function

I'm writing a function in PHP. This function will take 1 integer parameter, calculate the sum of all the numbers that came before and up to that number, and return the result. For example, if I pass it "10", it will return the sum 1+2+3+4, etc. up to and including 10.

If the number passed is a negative number, or is not a number, I'm supposed to return false. Now this is where my problem is. If I pass -1 as a value, nothing happens, and if I pass a string, I get the following error: "Warning: is_nan() expects parameter 1 to be double, string given in /nfs/home/h/h/Sum.php on line 11 hello"

Can't seem to figure out how to fix this. Here is my code:

```
        function findSummation($aNum)
        {
            if(is_nan($aNum) || $aNum < 0)
            {
                return false;
            }

            $result = $aNum;

            while($aNum > 0)
            {
                $result += --$aNum;
            }
            return $result;
        }
```

Also a side question, this kind of exercise can be done using the concept of recursion. Does PHP support recursion?

Comment: You can google `Does PHP support recursion`.

Comment: works for me: http://ideone.com/s50L80

Comment: read this link, you are getting it wrong about the is_nan http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-nan.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`is_nan()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-nan.php) does not do what you think it does. Use [`is_int()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php) instead.

Comment: Specifically, is_nan() is typically used for detecting [invalid floating point operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN).

Comment: Also, not sure exactly what OP considers "not a number" but http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

Comment: If I do this, is_int displays the string itself. While this is probably what I need (will ask my professor), isn't it supposed to display false? Just trying to understand how php works

Comment: @JKawa is_int does not display anything, it just returns a boolean.

Comment: Yes but what I meant is if I do the following: echo findSummation("hello"), this outputs hello on the page

Answer (score 0):

[Gauss](http://mathandmultimedia.com/2010/09/15/sum-first-n-positive-integers/) is your friend, you dont need recursion:

```
function findSummation($aNum)
{
    if( !is_int($aNum) || $aNum < 0 )
    {
        return false;
    }
    return $aNum*($aNum + 1)/2;
}
```

See also [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF).